# Calculating Time of a query php & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, execution-time

I am trying to calculate the time it takes a query to run using a php script:

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `order_items` LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `oi_o_id` = `o_id` WHERE `o_status` = 'completed' AND `oi_p_id` = '10' LIMIT 1";
$sqlStart = getMicroTime();
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$sqlEnd = getMicroTime();
$sqlTime = $sqlEnd - $sqlStart;

echo $sqlTime;

function getMicroTime() {
    list($msec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    return floor($sec / 1000) + $msec;
}
```

This appears to work most of the time, but occasionally I get a negative value e.g. `-0.98840499995276`. **How is this possible? and is there a better way to get the query execution time?**

Thanks

Comment: Don't seem to **ever** get a negative number: http://codepad.org/rL6MWCoK

Comment: Unfortunately I do, thanks for Marc B for actually answering the question

Comment: @Neal Actually it does fail - I just increased to 1000 iterations and it failed on around 986 http://codepad.org/OVf9aoOR

Comment: It'd appear to be a timing glitch of some sort. Some minor mods to @Lizard's version and there's no negative times: http://codepad.org/UetGzU3l

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your microtime function is not necessary, simply do

```
$start = microtime(TRUE);
... do query
$end = microtime(TRUE);
```

passing in the TRUE value has microtime() return the timestamp as an actual float, not that moronic string format that some [truly nasty but accurate description of said person's intelligence] thought would be a useful way of returning the data.

Comment: With microtime() false this - $time = $time_end - $time_start; echo "Did nothing in $time_end - $time_start=$time seconds</br>"; produces this output - but somehow PHP got the math right - any idea what its actually is doing here?
Did nothing in 0.55040500 1321470419 - 0.55024300 1321470419=0.000162 seconds

Comment: with false, it returns a string. substracting two strings is essentially meaningless.

Comment: I agree - but when I tried it - it appears to work. Thats the strange thing.

Comment: because PHP will use the first number-looking bit it finds, which happens to be the msec value.  If the start is '987 456' and the end is '123 457' (real diff: 0.136 sec), you'll end up doing 123-987 = -864.

Comment: I understand the OP's problem - I am wonder why its working in php 5.3.6. Try this $time_start = microtime(false);
usleep(100);
$time_end = microtime(false);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "Did nothing in $time_end - $time_start=$time seconds</br>";
It is producing the correct result somehow

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes PHP use the 'E notation' to represent floating point numbers: if you wish to avoid this, you can use the round function in this way:

```
$start_time = (float) round(microtime(true) * 10000,0);
{your code here}
$finish_time = (float) round(microtime(true) * 10000,0);
$time = ($finish_time - $start_time) / 10000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm works for me - PHP manual does say this. Have you checked for subspace time anomalies :-)

```
This function is only available on operating systems that support the gettimeofday() system call.
```

Also tried the alternative method from PHP manual

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Sleep for a while
usleep(100);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
```